# How to prevent XSS & CSRF attack in .NET CORE Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, csrf, xss

I am building a new Web API in .Net Core  5 with Angular in the UI. How can I prevent XSS attacks as well as CSRF attacks in backend??

I know Angular by default has DOM sanitization enabled, but I want to have protection in API side as well. I have gone through some blogs but they discussed only Angular part. How can I protect the API ?

Answer (score 0):

[XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) and [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) cannot really be performed on a backend API. They are performed on the webapp client and there is where you should focus defending them.

However some extra protections steps you could take for XSS on the backend are:

- Filter input on arrival
- Use appropriate response headers utilizing Content-Type and X-Content-Type-Options headers
- Use Content Security Policy (CSP), see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)

Comment: I saw in some blogs they said to encode the output. But as the API is returning json data, then how can I encode that entire json data? Is there any helper method in .net core?

Comment: Angular escapes output by default, you do not need to worry about that.

Comment: Is there any way to safely send the data to UI. We can't trust UI because in Angular there is innerHTML, which will not encode the things. And moreover what if the UI was made up of using normal HTML, Js & jQuery. So, we can't trust the UI. How can we send safe data from API itself??

Comment: There is no such thing as sending safely data to the UI. The UI has to trust the backend. However, to prevent XSS, you can sanitize, validate and escape user input in the UI, so no malicious user input ever reaches the backend. And generally, you may apply the same practices on the backend APIs as well.